# Is $\mathbb{Q}$ connected on the metric space $(\mathbb{Q},d)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Where $d$ is the euclidian metric with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Comment: Consider the sets $[\pi,\infty)\cap\Bbb Q$ and $(-\infty,\pi]\cap\Bbb Q$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The sets $\{\,x\in\Bbb Q\mid x^2>2\,\}$ and $\{\,x\in\Bbb Q\mid x^2<2\,\}$ are disjoint non-empty open sets that cover $\Bbb Q$.